# Why is my jQuery plugin for removing text on focus and re-adding it on blur not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I would like the text in the value field of a text box to disappear when that text box gains focus, and then reappear in response to the eventual blur event - but only if the value is empty (that is, if the user hasn't entered anything after putting focus into the text box). So far, I have this:

```
this.each(function() {  
    obj = $(this);
    var initialText = obj.val();

    obj.focus(function () { 
        if(obj.val() === initialText)
            obj.val("");    
    });


    obj.blur(function () { 
        if(obj.val() ==="")
            obj.val(initialText);   
    });
});
```

This plugin works if I have only one element in the page.
If I have two elements then it doesn't work. Why would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obj variable isn't scoped to the function, it's globally scoped, so there will only be one of them -- set to the last one that the plugin is applied to.  Use the `var` keyword to scope the variable to the anonymous function alone so that there will be one for each thing that the plugin is applied to.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to write your plugin seperate from your code implementation.

Your plugin would look something like this:

```
 (function($) {
    $.fn.watermark = function() {  

       return this.each(function() {         
          var obj = $(this);
          var initialText = obj.val();

          obj.focus(function () { 
            if(obj.val() === initialText)
               obj.val(""); 
          });

         obj.blur(function () { 
            if(obj.val() ==="")
                obj.val(initialText);   
         });
       });
    };
 })(jQuery);
```

Then to use your plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.watermark').watermark();

});
```

Additionally as tvanfosson you'll want to include the `var` keyword on your `obj`.  If you don't have the `var` keyword on your `obj` declaration only the last textbox will have the watermark effect.

Comment: Thanks guys that worked. I was also woding sometimes that why we use var sometimes and now i understand